# R- Sample random row per group until reaching max number of rows

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sample

I have a data set from which I want to take a random sample by group up to 30 rows.  However, I also want to make sure that at least 1 row for another grouping is included.  Additionally, some groups have less than 30 rows, in which case all of the rows for that group should be included.  I can't include the exact data set I'm working with because it's proprietary; however, an example for a data frame df would be:

ID|Age|State|Gender|Salary

1      25      CO        M        50000 
2      34      CO        M        72000 
3      28      CO        M        52000 
4      25      CO        F        44000 
5      25      CA        F        55000 
6      34      CA        F        100000 
7      39      CA        M        88000 
8      34      CA        M        59000 
... up to 15000 rows

So, I want a random sample of the data set so that no more than 30 rows are given from each state.  Then, for each state, I want at least 1 row for each age and gender that exists in the data set.  If there are less than 30 age/gender combinations for a given state, but there are more than 30 rows for that state, then the sample should include multiple rows for a given age/gender so that 30 rows are given for that state.  If there are less than 30 rows for that state, then I want all the rows in the data set for that state.  If there are more than 30 age/gender combinations for a given state, then the sample should have 1 of each up to 30.

Is there a way for me to do this in R?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting a question, you'll find it most helpful to provide easily reproducible code and a mock version of the result you expect (or hope for). Providing a sample of the data using dput(head(data,20)), for example, helps us get started helping you faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that takes you half the way. First I simulated data, that resembles yours.

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    ID = 1:1500,
    Age = sample(18:99, 1500, replace = TRUE),
    State = sample(state.abb, 1500, replace = TRUE),
    Gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 1500, replace = TRUE),
    Salary = sample(44:100 * 1000, 1500, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

Then with `group_by()` you can create the state grouping, determine the rows per state with `mutate()` and `n()`. That information can then be used to draw samples with `sample_n()`, that adjust to the group size.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(n_state = n()) %>% 
  sample_n(ifelse(n >= 30, 30, n))
```

This could be extended to calculate further group sizes you mention to use that information to ensure you hit the quotas you are looking for. Unfortunately I do no fully understand what your quotas are from your question.